# Appropriate way of stopping AWS RDS Instances having Multi AZ

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-rds

AWS RDS instances cannot be stopped if they are configured in Multi AZ Environment. An answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46439040/why-cant-i-stop-rds-instance) suggests that we should disable Multi AZ, stop and then start instance again. My questions are

1. What happens to the replica created during the Multi AZ?
2. Will it create a new replica when we restart the instance with AZ?

If any of the above two happens, the IO freeze while re creating Multi AZ will be quite higher (as db has lots of data). Requesting your insights. I need to stop our staging environment but need to ensure above points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What happens to the replica created during the Multi AZ?

It's detached and destroyed when you disable multi-AZ.

> Will it create a new replica when we restart the instance with AZ?

Yes, after restarting and reconfiguring the instance for multi-AZ, a new failover instance will be created in a second AZ.  It will take some time for this to become ready.

> the IO freeze while re creating Multi AZ will be quite higher (as db has lots of data).

Have you observed this?  The IO freeze should be minimal, since it does not need to copy the entire data set during the freeze -- it should only last long enough to establish a safe snapshot from which to clone the master instance onto a second machine.  The rest of the synchronization should occur in the background.